# Finding three parts of string in Python using regex

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I have three a string that is the concatenation of three components:

- one word from list 1 (includes an empty string)
- one word from list 2
- one word from list 3 (includes an empty string)

Lists 1, 2 and 3 can be up to 5000 elements. Elements in one list are not in the others (except of the empty string). However, there are words that can be part of other words.

I am looking for an efficient way to find the three components. Right now I am doing the following:

```
for word in list2:
    if word in long_word:
        try:
           [bef, aft] = long_word.split(word)
        except ValueError: # too many values to unpack
           continue
        if bef in list1 and aft in list3:
           print('Found: {}, {}, {}'.format(bef, word, aft))
           break
else:
    print('Not found')
```

I wonder if there is a better way. I thought about using the pipe in a regex. But it seems that the number of alternatives are too big as I get: OverflowError: regular expression code size limit exceeded.

Thanks,

### Update

I tried a modified version of the proposed solutions:

```
def fj(long_word, list1, list2, list3):
    for x in filter(long_word.startswith, list1):
        for y in filter(long_word[len(x):].startswith, list2):
            z = long_word[len(x)+len(y):]
            if z in list3:
                yield x, y, z

def sid(long_word, list1, list2, list3):
    for w1 in list1:
        if not long_word.startswith(w1):
            continue
        cut1 = long_word[len(w1):]
        for w2 in list2:
           if not cut1.startswith(w2):
               continue
           cut2 = cut1[len(w2):]
           for w3 in list3:
               if cut2 == w3:
                   yield w1, w2, w3

def my(long_word, list1, list2, list3):
    for word in list2:
        if word in long_word:
            try:
               [bef, aft] = long_word.split(word)
            except ValueError: # too many values to unpack
               continue
            if bef in list1 and aft in list3:
               yield bef, word, aft
```

This are the (normalized) results for the timing that I get using lists with 8000 elements repeating 10000 times, each time picking randomly one word from each list to generate long_word

- my: 1.0
- sid: 4.5
- fj: 2.7

I am really surprised as I thought that fj's method was going to be fastest.

Comment: you compare performance to your incomplete solution (`except ValueError:` will continue very fast indeed but will give you wrong results - especially if there are lots of repeated words from `list2`)

Comment: There a not repeated words within a list or between lists. Moreover, In my test script I have compared the results of all three scripts and I always get the same results.

Comment: then you should `raise` instead of `continue`... or at least print some debug message - you could have *'aaa'* in list1 and *'aa'* in list2 for example - even if your test results are correct, your script might fail prematurely in cases that could be matches but in your data are not (of course,, it might be faster even after you correct it)

Comment: Thanks for the comment!. It is a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions probably aren't a great fit here, I would probably go about it like this:

```
for x in filter(long_word.startswith, list1):
    for y in filter(long_word[len(x):].startswith, list2):
        z = long_word[len(x)+len(y):]
        if z in list3:
            print('Found: {}, {}, {}'.format(x, y, z))
            break
    else:
        continue
    break
else:
    print('Not found')
```

Comment: I found a faster version inspired in yours. See my update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

A naive algorithm would be to run 3 loops:

```
for w1 in list1:
    p1=re.match(w1,s)
    if p1==None:
        continue
    for w2 in list2:
       p2=re.match(w2,s[p1.pos+len(w1):])  
       if p2==None:
         continue
       for w3 in list3:
           p3=re.match(w3,s[p2.pos+len(w2):])
```

I think you're still stuck with the problem of substrings of list1 being parts of list2. F.J's method may be better.

Answer (score 0):

My answer does not completely answer your question, but it does remind us of what we are dealing with in this quesiton.

> Lists 1, 2 and 3 can be up to 5000 elements.

This implies that Lists 1, 2, and 3 are [finite regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Finite_languages). From here on out, I will denote List 1 as A, List 2 as B, and List 3 as C.

> - one word from list 1 (includes an empty string)
> - one word from list 2
> - one word from list 3 (includes an empty string)

Thus, the empty string (lambda) is in A and C.

You have a string w which can be written in the form

> w = abc

where a is a string in A, b is a string in B, and c is a string in C.

What you are attempting to do is split w into the substrings a, b, and c.

Since a can be empty and c can be empty, you have the following possibilities:

1. w = abc
2. w = ab
3. w = bc
4. w = b

For starters, let's eliminate the trivial scenario of #4.

```
if w in B:
  a = ""
  b = w
  c = ""
  print('Found: {}, {}, {}'.format(a, b, c))
```

More information to come as I think this over.